# How can I get the highest value in a column by sorting the date in a CSV file using Python?

Tags: python

How can I get the highest value in a column by sorting the date in a CSV file using Python?

My code:

```
if sys.argv[1] == "-p":
    c = sys.argv[2]
    col_name= r"\\DT001\Process(SK)\Virtual"
    #d = sys.argv[3]
    col_name2 = r"(PDH-CSV 4.0) (GMT Standard Time)(0)"

    with open(c, 'rb') as inf:
        reader = csv.reader(inf)
        col_index = next(reader).index(col_name)
        highest = float(max(rec[col_index] for rec in reader))

        reader2 = csv.reader2(inf)
        col_index2 = next(reader).index(col_name2)
        date = '7/19/2011' 


        #gigabytes = highest / 1073741824
        gigabytes = highest /1024/1024/1024
        print "Performance Counters Peak:\n", gigabytes, "GB"
```

I was able to sort the highest value but I am unable to figure out how to get the highest value by sorting the desired date in the CSV file using the Python script.

Comment: Can you show few lines of CSV?

Comment: Please don't crosspost on the StackExchange network.  This question is on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

use this snippet

```
from  time import strptime
def filterByDate(mydate , start,end):
    format = "%m/%d/%Y"
    return strptime(start,format) <= strptime(mydate,format) and strptime(mydate,format) <= strptime(end,format)
...
...
highest = float(max(rec[col_index] for rec in reader if filterByDate(rec[date_col_index],startDate,endDate)))
```